# Is there an event that occurs when Outlook completes indexing emails?

Tags: vba, vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm working on a tool to search a mailbox for emails shortly after a large number of messages are copied over from a pst file.  But, I do not want this action to begin until Outlook has had an opportunity to index all the emails.  Is there an event that tells me when Outlook's indexing process is complete?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you searching? If you use Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict, Windows Search is not used, so you don't have to wait for indexing to finish.

Comment: I'm using an AdvancedSearch.

Comment: Application.AdvancedSearchComplete event will fire.

Comment: Dmitry, maybe I misunderstand, but from what I've read, the AdvancedSearch will run regardless if Outlook's indexing is up to date or not, and as a result, so will the complete event.

Comment: If you call Search.Save (returns MAPIFolder object), Outlook will create a MAPI search folder, which does not use Windows Search.

Comment: I am not familiar with Search.Save.  I searched for more info on Google, but didn't find much.  Is the an MSDN page or other location you can point me where I might find more details on it's use?  Thanks.

Comment: After reading the MSDN, using Search.Save does not accomplish what I'm trying to do.  I'd like to delay running the AdvancedSearch until after Outlook's indexing function is complete.

Comment: So why not use Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict?